# SSIS Xpath query expression error

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, ssis

I'm trying to call a SalesForce web service via SSIS, and I am trying to retrieve the value of the sessionID node.

Here is the XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<LoginResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <metadataServerUrl xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">https://xxxxxx/services/Soap/m/31.0/xxxxxx</metadataServerUrl>
  <passwordExpired xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">false</passwordExpired>
  <sandbox xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">true</sandbox>
  <serverUrl xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">https://xxx/services/Soap/u/31.0/xxx</serverUrl>
  <sessionId xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">xxxxxxxxxx</sessionId>
  <userId xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">xxx</userId>
  <userInfo xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
    <accessibilityMode>false</accessibilityMode>
    <currencySymbol>$</currencySymbol>
    <orgAttachmentFileSizeLimit>5242880</orgAttachmentFileSizeLimit>
    <orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode>USD</orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode>
    <orgDisallowHtmlAttachments>false</orgDisallowHtmlAttachments>
    <orgHasPersonAccounts>false</orgHasPersonAccounts>
    <organizationId>xxxxxxxx</organizationId>
    <organizationMultiCurrency>false</organizationMultiCurrency>
    <organizationName>xxxxx</organizationName>
    <profileId>xxxxx</profileId>
    <roleId xsi:nil="true" />
    <sessionSecondsValid>7200</sessionSecondsValid>
    <userDefaultCurrencyIsoCode xsi:nil="true" />
    <userEmail>xxxxxxx</userEmail>
    <userFullName>xxxxx</userFullName>
    <userId>xxxxxxx</userId>
    <userLanguage>en_US</userLanguage>
    <userLocale>en_US</userLocale>
    <userName>xxxxxxx</userName>
    <userTimeZone>America/New_York</userTimeZone>
    <userType>Standard</userType>
    <userUiSkin>Theme3</userUiSkin>
  </userInfo>
</LoginResult>
```

I successfully tested this expression via http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath.

Edit:
Trying a script task now, and still I'm not finding the exact right combination to select this information. There are multiple namespaces in the XML, and the below code returns 0 nodes. Quite frustrating!

```
public void Main()
    {
        string loginResult;
        string sessionID;

        loginResult = Dts.Variables["User::loginResult"].Value.ToString();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(loginResult);

        var xmlnsManager = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        //xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("t1", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

        xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("ns", "urn:partner.soap.sforce.com");

        XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("/LoginResult/ns:sessionID", xmlnsManager);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            sessionID = list[i].Value;
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct expression to find the `sessionId` element is:

```
//*[local-name() = 'sessionId']/text()
```

In your input XML, the element you'd like to find:

```
<sessionId xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">xxxxxxxxxx</sessionId>
```

does *not* have a prefix - it is in a default namespace that does not require elements to be prefixed.
Therefore, a possible explanation is that an expression like

```
//*:sessionId
```

only finds elements that are prefixed in the input XML. That should not be a problem but as far as I can see, SSIS is known for problems with namespaced XML (see e.g. [here](http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2008/07/23/using-the-xml-task-to-run-an-xpath-query/) or [here](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/RussLoski/ssas/2670/ssis-2012-xml-source-what-hasn-t-changed)).

As far as the XPath specification is concerned, an expression like `//*:root` should be able to find an element like

```
<root xmlns="www.example.com"/>
```

---

**EDIT**: Apparently, you have changed the question alltogether - now there is another problem: The outermost element `LoginResult` is in *no* namespace at all, not in the `xsi:` namespace:

```
<LoginResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

The schema instance namespace just happens to be declared on this element, but it is not used there. So, change your code to:

```
var xmlnsManager = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("ns", "urn:partner.soap.sforce.com");

XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("/LoginResult/ns:sessionId", xmlnsManager);
```

Comment: seeing the article with the XML bugs/hacks makes me think I'll just use another method to do what I want. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my code in the original post to show what I tried. It still selects 0 nodes.

Comment: @Jeremy Also, lowercase the last character of `sessionId`. XPath is case-sensitive.

Comment: Ah. Problem Exists Between Keyboard And Chair. Thank you much!